# Why does a method defined on my `User` class keep returning undefined method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have this method defined in my `User` class:

```
  def two_way_exists_with?(user1, user2)
    return true if number_of_memberships(user1, user2) == 2
  end
```

When I try to call it from my console I keep getting an `undefined method` error.

```
[3] pry(main)> two_way_exists?(u1, u2)
NoMethodError: undefined method `two_way_exists?' for main:Object
from (pry):3:in `__pry__'
[4] pry(main)> u1.two_way_exists?(u1, u2)
NoMethodError: undefined method `two_way_exists?' for #<User:0x007fe9e7eda228>
from /ruby-2.1.6@global/gems/activemodel-4.1.12/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:435:in `method_missing'
[5] pry(main)> User.two_way_exists?(u1, u2)
NoMethodError: undefined method `two_way_exists?' for #<Class:0x007fe9eaabf0a0>
from /ruby-2.1.6@global/gems/activerecord-4.1.12/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:26:in `method_missing'
```

How do I invoke this method?

Comment: You define a method named `two_way_exists_with?` and try to call a method named `two_way_exists?`. Notice the missing `_with` in the name.

Comment: zomg....thanks for that tip. So what's the right way to call that? On the `u1` object, the `User` class or neither?

Comment: Without seeing where exactly you have defined the method, you probably gave defined an instance method. These are available in instances of your class, i.e. probably on `u1`. Generally, you should get an introduction book to ruby and learn a bit about method scopes. This is super basic stuff you will need all the time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you've defined it in your User class as you illustrate, then it's an instance method and you'd run it with a user as the receiver.

e.g.

```
u1.two_way_exists_with?(u1, u2)
```

However since it is an instance method, you already have one of the user objects available to you as `self` so you would just need to pass in the other user.

```
def two_way_exists_with?(other_user)
  return true if number_of_memberships(self, other_user) == 2
end

u1.two_way_exists_with?(u2)
```

As `number_of_memberships` is probably also an instance method, chances are good that you don't need to pass two users into that method either.